# How to capture the transactions while doing testing using Mocha

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am in the process of writing unit/behavioural tests using Mocha for a particular blockchain network use-case. Based on what I can see, these tests are not hitting the actual fabric, in other words, they seem to be running in some kind of a simulated environment. I don't get to see any of the transactions that took place as a part of the test. Can someone please tell me if it is somehow possible to capture the transactions that take place as part of the Mocha tests?

Initial portion of my code below:

```
describe('A Network', () => {
// In-memory card store for testing so cards are not persisted to the file system
const cardStore = require('composer-common').NetworkCardStoreManager.getCardStore( { type: 'composer-wallet-inmemory' } );
let adminConnection;
let businessNetworkConnection;
let businessNetworkDefinition;
let businessNetworkName;
let factory;
//let clock;
// Embedded connection used for local testing
const connectionProfile = {
    name: 'hlfv1',
    'x-type': 'hlfv1',
    'version': '1.0.0'
};
before(async () => {

    // Generate certificates for use with the embedded connection
    const credentials = CertificateUtil.generate({ commonName: 'admin' });

    // PeerAdmin identity used with the admin connection to deploy business networks
    const deployerMetadata = {
        version: 1,
        userName: 'PeerAdmin',
        roles: [ 'PeerAdmin', 'ChannelAdmin' ]
    };
    const deployerCard = new IdCard(deployerMetadata, connectionProfile);
    console.log("line 63")
    const deployerCardName = 'PeerAdmin';
    deployerCard.setCredentials(credentials);
    console.log("line 65")
    // setup admin connection
    adminConnection = new AdminConnection({ cardStore: cardStore });
    console.log("line 69")

    await adminConnection.importCard(deployerCardName, deployerCard);
    console.log("line 70")
    await adminConnection.connect(deployerCardName);
    console.log("line 71")
});
```

Earlier, my connection profile was using the embedded mode, which I changed to `hlfv1` after looking at the answer below. Now, I am getting the error: `Error: the string "Failed to import identity. Error: Client.createUser parameter 'opts mspid' is required." was thrown, throw an Error :)`. This is coming from
`await adminConnection.importCard(deployerCardName, deployerCard);`. Can someone please tell me what needs to be changed. Any documentation/resource will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a real Fabric. Which means you could interact with the created transactions using your test framework or indeed other means such as REST or Playground etc.

In Composer's own test setup, the option for testing against an `hlfv1` Fabric environment is used in its setup (ie whether you want to use embedded, web or real Fabric) -> see https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-tests-functional/systest/historian.js#L120

Setup is captured here 
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-tests-functional/systest/testutil.js#L192

Example of setting up artifacts that you would need to setup to use a real Fabric here 
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-tests-functional/systest/testutil.js#L247

Also see this blog for more guidelines -> https://medium.com/@mrsimonstone/debug-your-blockchain-business-network-using-hyperledger-composer-9bea20b49a74